# using database data to mark some checklistbox items as checked

Tags: c#, sql

i have a windows form which loads data from a table `(tblMinistries)` (**eg of data** `A B C D E`) into a checklistbox `(cblMinistries)`. there is another table `(tblMembershipministry)` (**eg of data** `A B C` ) which also contains data. Now i want when a button is clicked the SQL statement should run, Loop through the records then Find the matching checkbox list item in the two table and check them in the checklistbox.
i tried something like this but did not work

```
public void Newsearch() {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=PIWCDB;User ID=sa;Password=mike";

    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT Ministryname FROM tblMembershipministry WHERE FormattedMembershipid = '" + this.txtMembershipid.Text + "'";
    // System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dr = null;
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    using(SqlDataAdapter people = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn)) {
        DataTable people1 = new DataTable();
        people.Fill(people1);

        foreach(DataRow row in people1.Rows) {
            cblMinistries.SetItemCheckState(checked);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Connection and Command should be wrapped in a using too, and this is vunerable to SQL injection attack. Parameterise the query. I would also use a DataReader instead of a DataAdapter.

Comment: What didn't work? Do you get an error or an exception?

Comment: i get an syntax error '( expected' on this line  cblMinistries.SetItemCheckState(checked);